# How can I change log4j logs with start of classname

Tags: selenium, log4j

Logging as

> 30/09/2016 22:46:44 devpinoyLogger Test starts from 1

My Expectation as

> 30/09/2016 22:46:44 ClassName Info: Test starts from 1
>   30/09/2016 22:46:44 ClassName Error: Error on start

Code I used as

```
public class ComposeMailPage extends BasePage { 
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger("devpinoyLogger");
    log.warn("Test starts from 1"); 
    log.error("Error on start");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**%c{1}** will print the classname.Refer the below sample.

```
log4j.appender.INFO.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}  %-5p  %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

This will give the log as below.

```
2016-09-15 09:25:10  INFO   Classname:lineNumber
```

**{1}** in %c{1} means , it will print the **last part** from the **fully** qualified class name.

As described in the [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html) for **%C** below.

> For example, for the class name "org.apache.xyz.SomeClass", the
>   pattern %C{1} will output "SomeClass".
>
> **WARNING** Generating the caller class information is slow. Thus, use
>   should be avoided unless execution speed is not an issue.